# Angular google maps custom Icon only works when marker is updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

When I add a marker with a icon filed it appears as a default marker, however when I update the location in a while it starts to appear as a custom icon which I want.

**map.html**

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center"
            control="map.control"
            zoom="map.zoom"
            options="map.options"
            bounds="map.bounds"
            draggable="true">
    <ui-gmap-markers
            models="markerArray"
            coords="'self'"
            icon="'icon'">
    </ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

**map.js/addMarker**  (puts the marker, with the default icon)

```
function addMarker(markerId, latitude, longitude, icon, iconSize) {

    markerIconSize = new google.maps.Size(iconSize[0],iconSize[1]);

    var marker = {
        id: markerId,
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude, 
        icon: {
            url: icon,
            scaledSize: markerIconSize
        }
    };
    $scope.markers.push(marker);
    $scope.markerArray = $scope.markers;
}
```

**map.js/updateMarker** (updates the coord. with the custom icon)

```
function updateMarker(markerId,latitude,longitude) {

     var marker = _.find($scope.markerArray, function(marker) {
          return marker.id = markerId;
     });

     marker.latitude = latitude;
     marker.longitude = longitude;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things I could think of:
Try hard coding the icon url and see if that works.
Then try to split marker declaration, so:

```
var marker;
var markerOptions = {
    id: markerId,
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude, 
    icon: {
        url: icon,
        scaledSize: markerIconSize
    }
};
marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
$scope.markers.push(marker);
$scope.markerArray = $scope.markers;
```

This is how I made my map work so, just giving you a suggestion. Hope it works for you as well.